# App takes longer time for loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am developing iOS app. I have more number of view controller in the storyboard. When i build the app for first time it takes longer time for loading (nearly 30 mins). After the first build it takes lesser time to build the app. and also if i made any changes in the storyboard then the app takes longer time to build the app(nearly 30 mins). My app size is 33 MB. I can’t figure it out where the problem arise . I think the problem is in the storyboard that i am using more number of view controller in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have put too many viewcontrollers in your storyboard. If the storyboard isnt touched after a build, it wont have to recompile a lot of things to do with it again. If it is touched it will have to recompile the whole thing. If you separate out sections to different storyboards you shouldnt feel these effects as much.

A first time build will always be the longest though as it will be compiling from scratch and wont be able to reuse already compiled sections of the program

Comment: Whats the solution to avoid this lagging.

Comment: you need to break up your storyboard into multiple smaller ones

Answer (score 0):

Fonix is right. You need to bifurcate your storyboard, or maybe divide-into-multiple even. Editing anything on the storyboards forces it to recompile it to run.

Follow the best practices for storyboards mentioned [here](http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.pt/2012/01/uistoryboard-best-practices.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think Fonix is right. If your app still takes longtime to build. There maybe something wrong on your computer. I meant the same problem with you. And try many methods, but it does not work. Finally I Found my computer`s disk had bad tracks